# Seriously, why does this scanf not work in Netbeans 8.2 for C

Tags: c, scanf, netbeans-8

Example...

```
int main()
{
int i,j,k;
printf("Enter two integers: \n");
scanf("%d",&i);
scanf("%d",&j);

k = i + j;
printf("Adding %d and %d gives %d.\n", i, j, k);

return 0;
}
```

Before someone just links to this... [Programs with the scanf not working properly in NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116958/programs-with-the-scanf-not-working-properly-in-netbeans)

Is it seriously not possible to run this code using the internal terminal of Netbeans? I tried searching around and someone said to put a flush statement after that printf. It still didn't work.

Also, I already have a return of 0; which was indicated in that other answer (link above).

Comment: This has to with newline char that gets entered.  Try this: char garbage[50];  After each scanf(), enter fgets(garbage, sizeof(garbage), stdin);  Hope this fixes it!!!

Comment: "It doesn't work" is a vague description. Please explain what your output is.

Comment: @Nguaial `%d` already skips leading whitespace characters, so I doubt it is the problem

Comment: I don't link the linked question, but did you read the [not accepted upvoted answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15130185/3436922)

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue with openjdk 1.8 and netbeans 8.2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilIUv.gif

Comment: And what does `scanf()` return?  You're not bothering to check the return value...

Comment: Include `<stdio.h>`. Above code compiles and runs perfectly. **show your input values**, so that someone can help. @Doctor Questions